# "babelHelpers.interopRequireDefault is not a function" when upgrading to React Native 0.16.0-rc

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I upgraded to react-native 0.16.0-rc, ran npm install, then ran react-native upgrade. When trying to launch the iOS app in a simulator (or device, doesn't matter) I get the error:

> [error][tid:com.facebook.React.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: babelHelpers.interopRequireDefault is not a function. (In 'babelHelpers.interopRequireDefault(_reactNative)', 'babelHelpers.interopRequireDefault' is undefined)

I've just about run out of ideas here. Is there something I need to add to my xcode project maybe? Merging the latest react-native templates into mine was a nightmare so maybe something got messed up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is discussed in this Github [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4327#issuecomment-160224557) and fixed by this [commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/ffea7793aff0961ebc22007d650ce36f7c2e61cb). You can apply this patch temporarily until it is merged into the project with the version 0.16.