# React-Native Production APK crashes with a "babelHelpers.interopRequireDefault object is not a function" error

Tags: react-native, babeljs

Been developing mobile apps using react-native for a good few months now but recently I've been coming across the following issue when creating release APK's...

`ReactNativeJS: Object is not a function (evaluating '(0,babelHelpers.interopRequireDefault(u).default)()')`

The only reference I've been able to find when debugging this issue is one from 2015 (["babelHelpers.interopRequireDefault is not a function" when upgrading to React Native 0.16.0-rc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052847/babelhelpers-interoprequiredefault-is-not-a-function-when-upgrading-to-react-n)) but unfortunately it offers little assistance when figuring this issue out especially as it was targeted at react-native 0.16 and was promptly resolved.

This issue is only thrown when launching the release APK under `Android` (accessible via `adb logcat`) on either a device or emulator and there are no issues or error logs thrown when in dev mode.

In terms of the environment, I'm currently running the following:

- yarn: 1.7.0
- node: 10.4.0
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.55.4
- gradle: 2.14.1

package.json contains the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-bgimage": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.463",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^23.0.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-config-react-native": "^2.0.0",
    "jest": "^23.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
},
"jest": {
   "preset": "react-native"
}
```

Build configuration includes both proguard and separate architecture builds enabled but I have tested the release APK's with both options set to `false`.

Not sure what else I can provide or where to look next, advise is much appreciated as this has been investigated for a while now :(

Let me know if any additional info is required.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am also facing same issue...

Comment: No, I never found a solution to this particular problem but I did find a work around for the time being which was to revert to a previous version of ReactNative v0.14 and then the bulds work fine.

I have a bit of spare time over the next few weeks so I'm going to look at resolving the issue ... if it's not already been resolved (guessing it hasn't)